# The result of PHP code is wrong?

Tags: php

When I tried make a simple PHP code, I had a problem that the result had showed some things which weren't expected such as "***' . "\n"; echo'*** ". Where is my code wrong?

Here is my code:

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Putting Data in the DB</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*insert students into DB*/
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$db = mysql_connect("mysql", "martin");
mysql_select_db("martin");
$date=date("Y-m-d");  /* Get the current date in the right SQL format */
$sql="INSERT INTO students  VALUES(NULL,'" . $_POST["f_name"] . "','" . 
$_POST["l_name"] . "'," . $_POST["student_id"] . ",'" . $_POST["email"] . 
"','" . $date . "'," . $_POST["gr"] . ")";  /* construct the query */
mysql_query($sql);  /* execute the query */ 
mysql_close();
echo"<h3>Thank you. The data has been entered.</h3> \n";
echo'<p><a href="data_in.php">Back to registration</a></p>' . "\n";
echo'<p><a href="data_out.php">View the student lists</a></p>' ."\n";
}
else {
?> 
<h3>Enter your items into the database</h3>
<form action="data_in.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="f_name" /> <br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="l_name" /> <br/>
ID: <input type="text" name="student_id" /> <br/>
email: <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
Group: <select name="gr">
<option value ="1">1</option>
<option value ="2">2</option>
<option value ="3">3</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" /> <input type="reset" />
</form>
<?php
} /* end of "else" block */
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is here:

> Thank you. The data has been entered. \n"; echo' Back to registration
>
> ' . "\n"; echo' View the student lists
>
> ' ."\n"; } else { ?> Enter your items into the database

Comment: `<?php` open and `?>` close

Comment: PHP is not being processed. If it were, you'd have syntax errors. Are you running this on a server?

Comment: And let's not even get started on the massive SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I added some new information, can you review it again?. In addition, i realised that browser saw my php code that it ended at '<h3>' tag. Is that right?

Comment: Separate concerns - use sprintf to form your SQL statement outside of your HTML, and you should solve this one.  It looks like your complex quoting is confusing you.  If code looks confusing to you, imagine how hard it is for an interpreter like php to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Putting Data in the DB</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
    <?php
        /*insert students into DB*/
        $db = mysql_connect("mysql", "martin");
        mysql_select_db("martin");
        $date = date("Y-m-d");  /* Get the current date in the right SQL format */
        $sql = "INSERT INTO students  VALUES(NULL,'" . $_POST["f_name"] . "','" .
            $_POST["l_name"] . "'," . $_POST["student_id"] . ",'" . $_POST["email"] .
            "','" . $date . "'," . $_POST["gr"] . ")";  /* construct the query */
        mysql_query($sql);  /* execute the query */
        mysql_close();
    ?>
    <h3>Thank you. The data has been entered.</h3>
    <p><a href="data_in.php">Back to registration</a></p>
    <p><a href="data_out.php">View the student lists</a></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <h3>Enter your items into the database</h3>
    <form action="data_in.php" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="f_name"/> <br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="l_name"/> <br/>
        ID: <input type="text" name="student_id"/> <br/>
        email: <input type="text" name="email"/> <br/>
        Group: <select name="gr">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/> <input type="reset"/>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

By the way, please try to use PDO
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
Otherwise somebody can enter `"); TRUNCATE table students; --` and clear all your data.

It's classic - https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Although you may be helpfully solving the apparent issue, this is really not "correct".  There are real problems with sql statements having POST parameters in them.  There is no error checking.

Comment: Sure, I also prefer to use Symfony and Doctrine when possible and DBAL or at least PDO otherwise. But it's not an answer to this question, unfortunately.